# Spring boot rest api retry logic to third party api

Tags: spring-boot, retry-logic

We have one rest API, when we call it. It makes another third party rest API call.

So if third part gives failed response,
then we need to retry based on configuration count and if the error code matches with configured error code in yml.

I am thinking to use normal while loop to make retry and check if retry count and error code matches then retry.

Is this correct way? Does it impact the performance?

Thanks,
Ashwini

Comment: here is the best way to implement retry https://shankulk.com/auto-retries-in-rest-api-clients-using-spring-retry-c78cacb0cc29

Comment: Look into `spring-retry` or `Hystrix` https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix